# Sharepoint mobile app for android

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Microsoft SharePoint app behaves differently for ios and android. In ios it is asking for the option Online/On Premise. Whereas, in andriod it takes you directly to online account login page.

Please suggest a free SharePoint mobile app to open On-Premise SharePoint sites.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check Microsoft PowerApps (https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) When user download Power App from MS, they can use the apps inside that developed by the organization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible today, but support for OnPremis is coming at a later date.

> To sign in to the SharePoint app, your organization needs to have an
>   Office 365 subscription (Enterprise, Education, Government and DvNext)
>   that includes SharePoint Online. Support for SharePoint Server 2013
>   and SharePoint 2016 will be added at a later date.

Reference: [Microsoft SharePoint Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.sharepoint&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in ios there seems to be an option to select Online/OnPremise.

Comment: @Sharanya True! And you can have both on the same time in the iOS app

Comment: Is it recommendable to use third party apps for viewing SharePoint sites?

Comment: If it works for the user, then yes - otherwise no

Comment: Do you have a timeline when Support for OnPermis will start?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But you can follow the updates on the link.